# How do i pass down navigation props to a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image]

Hey guys I have a bottom app bar component that I want to receive the navigation props. How do I do that? I tried calling this.props.navigation but it's not being passed in (I'm getting a value of undefined). Any help would be greatly appreciated. For reference I'm using https://reactnavigation.org/

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass it as props

Use withNavigation when exporting BottomAppBar

More Details: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/with-navigation/